# ASP.NET MVC last logged in user always replaces the previous logged in user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app.

On this ASP.NET MVC app getting the current user with

```
Welcome <strong>@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name</strong>
```

But I have verified that the last logged in user always replaces the previous logged in user

e.g.

the user `Foo` connects at hours 11:35 and on the `View` of app, I see on the browser

```
Welcome Foo
```

the user `Foo2` connects at hours 11:45 **from other devices** and on the `View` of app, I see on my browser

```
Welcome Foo2
```

The user `Foo` replaced on the app user `Foo2`...

If restart browser I see always

```
Welcome Foo2
```

How do fix this?

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're experiencing session management as it's intended to work. Note that each welcome message is determined by referencing `@HttpContext.Current`. This indicates the CURRENT user so when `Foo2` logs in after `Foo`, the current user is replaced. If you accessed the same site from 2 different browsers at the same time and logged in with each user respectively, you should see a different name reflecting each user.

Comment: @Ortund Thanks for reply. This MVC app working only th browser Google Chrome (company standard)... how can i avoid user replacement?